# Combine browser and web app for deployment

Tags: javascript, packaging

What's the best way to turn an HTML/Javascript web app into a self-contained app that can be run from Windows (and maybe Mac/Linux) PC's? Preferably without any installation, ie a network share.
I have looked into Chrome and Firefox Portable, but these require write access to the folder, so are unsuitable for running off a read-only network share.
(some background, I have a big javascript app but many of my clients are using IE6 or 7. Their IT teams won't allow Chrome Frame, or other modern browsers).

Comment: If they won't allow Chrome or other modern browsers, why would they allow your custom built software which attempts to emulate these?

Comment: Where would the app write back its changes on a read-only network share?

Comment: why not re-adapt it to IE 6/7?

Comment: @Curt the short answer is 'they will'. They are much more relaxed about a 'dedicated app' than another browser (even if that isn't logical).

Comment: @Pekka not an issue, any changes go to a DB via json.

Comment: @EliranMalka the problem here is speed, in my tests IE6/7 is very slow for my app

Comment: I'm looking into using Chromium Portable. It can be set up to run from a read-only share, silently copy itself to a temp folder, and then delete itself again when you exit. So my shortcut just runs 'chromium.exe --app=myurl'

Answer (score 0):

[node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) sounds most promising.

From the README on the github repository:

> node-webkit is an app runtime based on `Chromium` and `node.js`. You can
>   write native apps in HTML and Javascript with node-webkit. It also
>   lets you to call Node.js modules directly from DOM and enables a new
>   way of writing native applications with all Web technologies.

If [LightTable](http://www.chris-granger.com/lighttable/) can be built with it, certainly a web application can be ported and run natively using it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late, but what about Sencha Desktop Packager?

http://www.sencha.com/products/desktop-packager

It was primarily developed for ExtJS apps, but it should work on any JavaScript app.

We had a similar requirement and ended up building a dedicated web browser using QT. However if we'd known about the Sencha Desktop Packager before we may have gone for that.

Comment: I'm actually using ExtJS, I just wanted to avoid the costs of using the desktop packager (which I think is commercial only?). Using Chromium Portable seems to be working fine for me. And it's free!